# How can I make my javascript animation faster?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, css-transitions

I made a Vue component to make a div's loop over the X axis. But I noticed that it uses alot of CPU. I works like I want to but I would like to optimize it. How could I make my animation faster. The galeryItems moves over the x axis and when they reach the width of their parent div they get moves to the other side. So the keep looping. I would preferer not to use external plugins.

```
<template>
    <div class="placeholder">
      <div class="galery" ref="galery">
          <div class="galery-item" v-for="i in 10" :key="i" ref="galeryItems" />
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:{
      xoffset : {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
      },
      speed : {
        type: Number,
        default: 1,
      },
      spaceBetween : {
        type: Number,
        default: 50,
      },
    },
    data() {
      return {
      }
    },
    mounted(){
      for(let i = 0; i < this.$refs.galeryItems.length; i++)
        this.$refs.galeryItems[i].style.transform = 'translateX(' + (this.$refs.galeryItems[i].clientWidth + this.spaceBetween) * i + 'px)';
      this.animate();
    },
    methods:{
      animate(){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
        for(let i = 0; i < this.$refs.galeryItems.length; i++)
        {
          let galeryItemRect = this.$refs.galeryItems[i].getBoundingClientRect();
          if(galeryItemRect.x > this.$refs.galery.clientWidth)
          {
            this.$refs.galeryItems[i].style.transform = 'translateX(' + -galeryItemRect.width + 'px)';
            continue;
          }

          this.$refs.galeryItems[i].style.transform = 'translateX(' + (galeryItemRect.x + this.speed) + 'px)';
        }
      }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.placeholder{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.galery
{
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.galery-item{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  height: inherit;
  min-width: 100px;
  transition: 0s;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use external plugin , its better in performance and quality, in `vue.js` use the framework options like `v-animate` and `transition` in the link below:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

Comment: But how do I make an infinite animation with vue.js transitions?

Comment: insert this:  animation-iteration-count: infinite ; in enter and leave tag